# Broken links in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, pdf, url, system-environment

I'm stuck with a broken link problem. I installed Manjaro Linux and Emacs 27.2. I use org mode for my every day planning at work. I have a lot of internal links to open PDF, ODT, PNG files, etc.

Since my new install, the links don't open anymore. The path in the buffer is all messed up and I think it's related with my language environment (French) but I'm unable to find a solution.

Here is the path in the buffer and this is the good path: `/home/martin/MEGA/.CMDP/4.Departements/Urgence/Fluidité/Rapport intervention Anna_Laberge.pdf`

Any clues for a solution?

[image: buffer path]

Result for the `locale` command:

```
LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answering a question in a comment:
This command work fine and it open my document: `/usr/bin/xdg-open '/home/martin/MEGA/.CMDP/2.Comites/Obligatoires/CEAMDP/Départements/MédecineGénérale/Méd. fam. crit explicites 24 novembre 2021.pdf'`

org mode version 9.4.4 emacs 27.2

**Just found curiously that the link work with a right mouse click...but not with the left one** Weird...

Comment: Do links to URLs that don't contain characters such as é still work? In other words, are you sure that the problem comes from such chars?

Comment: If you do `M-x org-toggle-link-display`, the links in the Org mode file are going to be shown fully (the URL, as well as the description). Please cut and paste (as text) the URL and add it to your question. URL escaping is a tricky business and it may have something to do with your problem, but we have to see the original link to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.                                                                                             My URL links work fine.                                                                                               If I do the command M-x-toggle-link-display, the links seems good                                                                       [[/home/martin/MEGA/.CMDP/2.Comites/Obligatoires/CEAMDP/Départements/MédecineGénérale/Méd. fam. crit explicites 24 novembre 2021.pdf][24/11]]

Comment: The link is good (as shows by the command) but the documents still doesn't want to open  and curiously the link in the buffer is wrong when I click on the word to open the link

Comment: As you can see in the buffer, the link messed up where are the ''accent''             Running /usr/bin/xdg-open /home/martin/MEGA/.CMDP/2.Comites/Obligatoires/CEAMDP/D\épartements/M\édecineG\én\érale/M\éd.\ fam.\ crit\ explicites\ 24\ novembre\ 2021.pdf...done

Comment: The system add a "\" before each ''é'' character. That's probably why the link doesn't work, well I guess

Comment: Well yes - but it's not clear who adds the backslash (presumably trying to "escape" the accented characters). If you run `locale` in a shell, what do you get as output? Please update your question with the information: do not add comments. Comments can disappear at any time.

Comment: The `locale` information is as expected: nothing suspicious. If you take the URL as shown in the Org mode buffer and run the command `/usr/bin/xdg-open ` on the URL, e.g. `/usr/bin/xdg-open '/home/martin/MEGA/.CMDP/2.Comites/Obligatoires/CEAMDP/Départements/MédecineGénérale/Méd. fam. crit explicites 24 novembre 2021.pdf'` with single quotes around the URL, that works - correct? Again, just edit your question and add the information you get.

Comment: OK - thanks for the confirmation. Not sure what the next steps should be, but I'll try to write up something so that we can avoid the extended back-and-forth. Remote debugging is hard!

Comment: One last question for tonight: Can you do `M-x org-version` and add the exact version of Org mode you are using to the question?

Comment: By the way, thank you so much for your help!